# What is al-walaa' wal-baraa' and what is its significance?

Tags: al-walaa-wal-baraa

I came across [this post on meta](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/93/17702), and as an example to illustrate when to go into detail about terminology, it used something like the question title I'm posting. To my surprise, I can't find anything on al-walaa' wal-baraa' on islam.se, the closest seems to be [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14756/what-is-wala-of-a-slave) about the wala of slaves - I suppose wala/walaa' is related to the meaning of "wali".

I sometimes come across the expression, mostly in salafi materials, but it does seem to have a somewhat central significance in Islamic political ideas as well as a slightly important station in theology. Thus:

What is al-walaa' wal-baraa' and what is its significance, and in which aspects of Islam is it important? Do different schools of law/thought see different concepts here?

Comment: Really not my intention, I don't think that would be a productive question - but a concept like al-walaa' wal-baraa' should be explained somewhere on islam.se, right?

Comment: For the start https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al_Wala%27_Wal_Bara%27 the Arabic link has only salafi quotes or quotes of scholars accepted by salafis ;)

Answer (score 3):

**Al-walaa' :** be loyal to  .

**Al-baraa' :** wash your hands from or become innocent from or leave something away.

---

*in Islam conducts :*

**1- Be loyal** to Allah (by obeying his orders of what to do and not do), and his Prophet Mohammed -peace upon him-, and his companions , plus his followers and Muslim brothers.
(by loving them, supporting them, aiding & helping them and backing them up).

**2- Clear and innocent from** Allah infidels , polytheists , and dissemblers. 
(including all  their characteristics and similarities and acts and opposing them, not helping them)

but in some cases if they were one's parents , you should accompany them in the life with good turn but without opposing God's Orders.

---

**its significance in political :** be a loyal to your Muslim leader or group leader . and the inverse is correct by disobeying him if he is conflicting with Allah clear orders.

> 'Abdullah Bin Umar wrote to `Abdul Malik bin Marwan, swearing allegiance to him: 'I swear allegiance to you in that I will listen and obey what is in accordance with the Laws of Allah and the Tradition of His Apostle as much as I can.'     [Reference     : Sahih al-Bukhari 7272](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/96/5)

**its significance in Islam :**

**1-** its within the context meaning of "no god but Allah" as you should not obey any one else but Allah .

**2-** its a mandatory in faith's "Iman's" requirements as you should not obey the non-believers.

**3-** its the building block where Muslims community raise upon it.(faithful men are brothers)

**4-** not performing the walaa' and the baraa' may means you are infidel (by obeying the disbelievers)

**5-** its importance is due to mentioning it many times in the Quran Holy book and the Tradition of His Apostle (Prophet Mohammed peace upon him).

**6-** it distinguish you between the faith and the infidelity .

---

***as far as i know there is no interference between schools about above general clarifications .***

Comment: If you added a few more evidences I will consider this answer for the bounty. I'd appreciate also a commentary of OP on that!

Comment: I'd be interested if you could add some examples of what is expected in terms of being loyal to Muslims and in opposing the Non-Muslims. In particular, some non-trivial examples of what would constitute breaching al-walaa wal-baraa would be helpful.

Comment: "*as far as i know there is no interference between schools about above general clarifications .*" is true, but there's a difference in the interpretation. Therefore I'm still waiting for an improvement of this answer.